# Why is the intent from the MainActivity to AnotherActivity not working?

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, crash

The App crashes as soon as I call the next function in the MainActivity java file.
Here is [MainActivity](https://github.com/subha736121/SharedPrefference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/com/android/www/sharedprefference/MainActivity.java) and [AnotherActivity](https://github.com/subha736121/SharedPrefference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/com/android/www/sharedprefference/AnotherActivity.java) source code.

Comment: What's your error ?
you probably forgot to add AnotherActivity in your Manifest.xml

Comment: The App crashes with the error massage unfortunately,"SharedPrefference(app name)has stopped".I use Android Studio as my IDE so it is not required.

Comment: add crash reports and put code where it is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Manifest.xml` 
add `AnotherActivity`

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

You can't start your Activity if it's not in this file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it necessary for Android studio? I know that it is a absolute necessity for eclipse.

Comment: That not dependent of your IDE. It's just how Android works. You need it everytime on every IDE

Comment: Hey, the solution worked thanks a lot.But previously I have used intents in the slimier fashion for moving to activity A to activity B,but at that time AnotherActivity was was implicitly imported in the Manifest.xml.Can you tell me why it was not auto-imported this time?And thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: @helloandro in AndroidStudio if you create just a class it will not imported but if your create an Activity by doing right click > new activity, I think it will be imported. otherwise you have to do it yourself